# PHP error_log: Won't write to specified file

Tags: php, iis, error-log

Running PHP under IIS on my Win XP Pro system.  I cannot debug my scripts easily because get PHP to write to the error log I specify.  Here are the relevant (I think) php.ini entries:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_log = "c:/php5/log/php.log"
```

I had the slashes going the Windows/DOS way before.  In either case, it did not write to the file php.log in that directory.  The log file is writable by IUSR_SERVERNAME, the directory is writable by IUSR_SERVERNAME, the parent directory is writable by IUSR_SERVERNAME.  I'm sure I'm missing something stupid.

Any tips?

Comment: I found the problem. I updated my answer. Let me know how it goes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried in the php file itself?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', "c:/php5/log/php.log");
```

Update:
The problem is that you are using a bitwise AND where you should use a bitwise OR

Try this

```
var_dump(E_ALL);
var_dump(E_STRICT);
var_dump(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
var_dump(E_ALL & E_STRICT);
```

output:
int(6143) int(2048) int(8191) int(0)

So basically you are writing

```
error_reporting  =  0
```

Effectively turning off the error reporting.
Change the & for an | in your php.ini and you should be ok.

Comment: Kind of misses the point of having in the INI file, but I'll try it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be error_reporting  =  E_ALL | E_STRICT
 instead of error_reporting  =  E_ALL & E_STRICT?
& of E_ALL and E_STRICT will return all zeros I think

Comment: That was it, thank you very much!  Of course, it didn't log an error related to the initial problem, but that's a security issue I have to figure out, not related to the error log.

Comment: An interesting side note:  I just uncommented the line, so the initial PHP.ini file had it wrong.