# Errors not being written to error.log, inside a custom class

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've made a WordPress theme with a bunch of custom classes and custom functionality (this is more of a PHP-question though). In the past, whenever there had been an issue in one of those classes, then I could check the `wp-content/debug.log` to see what the problem was. This had been working for 6 months reliably.

But now I'm getting an error, where in the frontend it says:

> There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

But if I check `wp-content/debug.log`, then I can't see any error.

---

#### Solution attempt 1: Try to 'provoke' an error

I tried adding this to the top of my functions.php-file:

```
if( !empty( $_GET['test'] ) ){
    require('some/path/that/doesnt/exists.php' );
}
```

And then visit: https://example.org/?test=1234

And this results in a 'critical error' - and the output is written to `wp-content/debug.log`. The error being:

> [03-Aug-2021 09:20:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(some/path/that/doesnt/exists.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ... on line ...

However... If I move that faulty line (`require('some/path/that/doesnt/exists.php' );`) inside one of my custom classes, that I know is throwing the error, the I don't get anything in the debug.log. Hmm!

#### Solution attempt 2: Ensure debug.log wasnt too big

Sometimes I've seen wierd results, if the debug.log was enormous (like 50mb+). So I tried deleting it and creating a new. Same result.

#### Solution attempt 3: Ensure debugging-setting are setup properly

This is what I have in my wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

And since it throws the warning as it should on the faulty `require()`-function, then I think that is as it should be.

#### Solution attempt 4: Tried pointing to a different debug.log-file

I can change which file WordPress will write to, but replacing this line:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

with this line:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', 'wp-content/new-debug.log' );
```

But it's the same here: Still only some of the errors appears.

#### Solution attempt 5: Ensure error_reporting is set correctly

I tried following the [instructions on setting error_reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1345096/1766219) like suggested in that answer there.

But I'm still not getting the error in my debug.log-file.

If I write these lines:

```
var_dump(E_ALL);
var_dump(E_STRICT);
var_dump(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
var_dump(E_ALL & E_STRICT);
```

Then it outputs:

```
int(32767) int(2048) int(32767) int(2048)
```

Both, when doing it just after setting the ini_sets, in the `wp-config.php`-file, but also if I do it inside one of the classes that "doesn't write to the debug.log"-file. I'm not sure what that means, though.

#### Solution attempt 6: Clear cache

I tried clearing a bunch of cache: The server varnish cache. The cache setup using a WordPress-plugin. Nothing changed.

#### Solution attempt 7: Read WordPress Troubleshooting documentation

I read [WordPress Documentation on Troubleshooting](https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-troubleshooting/), but wasn't able to find anything in there.

#### Solution attempt 8: Copy to other server and try an replicate error (SUPER-WIERD!)

This is when it gets really wierd!

I copied the site to another server and at first the same problem was there: That I got the error in the frontend, but nothing was written to `wp-content/debug.log`.

Then I tried doing a binary-search for exactly what was causing this 'critical error'. So I went through the files adding the lines:

```
<?php
die('Do I make it this far?');
?>
```

And moving that down through the code. In the end, I figured out that it was this line here:

```
if( array_key_exists( $some_id, $shortlisted_part_ids ) ){
```

... where `$shortlisted_part_ids` is null (not an array).

But having found that, then I removed my 'die()'-statement AND THEN THE ERROR APPEARED IN THE `wp-content/debug.log`-FILE!? Without changing anything else, beside going through the code making it 'die' a bazillion times.

And note, that this is only on the development-server. If I add the same `die()`-statement to the production-server and then remove it again afterwards, then (*sigh*), still getting the critical error in the frontend and still nothing is written in the error-log.

#### Non-attempted solutions

- **List most recent changed files**: I figured that maybe a plugin or some code changes which debug-file to write to. So if I listed the most recent changed files, after getting a critical error, then it may show which file the error is being written to. I Googled around, trying to find this terminal-command - and played around with `grep` a bit, but I couldn't find the right command.
- **Boot server**: I haven't tried restarting the server, since it's a production environment, with a lot of visitors. And even if that solves it, then I hate relying on booting something, to make it work.
- **Deactivate plugins + change theme**: I haven't tried the usual: Deactivate all plugins and change to default theme', since - again - It's not a viable troubleshooting-technique,

#### Other comment

- **Xdebug**: I recently played around with setting up Xdebug on that server. Maybe I did something, while doing that. What I can't understand is what some of the errors shows up and some doesn't.
- **Admin email**: I received and email with the error, some of the times?!

Comment: have you looked into php apache log (/var/log/apache2/error_log)?

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. Why is it that the apache-logs should have a solution to this issues? What should I look for in that?

Comment: I apache log show any. PHP error. in code for fatal error.

Comment: if you find logs in apache, there are cases that malware blocks the output to debug.log. Try Anti malware plugin like below.
https://ja.wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/

Comment: You can check for recently modified files with something like `find . -type f -newermt '2021-08-19'`. Do the servers tested have the same PHP version installed?

Comment: @cezaryta That worked! And I found the other file, where I could find all the errors that had 'disappeared'. If you post your comment as a solution, then I can award you the bounty. For some reason, the errors are now displayed in `/wp-content/uploads/wc-logs/fatal-errors-DATETIMESTAMP-RANDOMSTRING.log`. I don't know why they weren't printed in there earlier. Some race-condition, I assume (because I haven't updated WooCommerce).

Comment: Thank you. By the way, good to know that WC might intercept errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently modified files can be found with something like
`find . -type f -newermt '2021-08-19'`. That's only part of the solution.

One also needs to have in mind that WooCommerce can intercept PHP errors and log them in `/wp-content/uploads/wc-logs/...`. (credit: [Zeth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766219/zeth)).

Comment: Perhaps add the contents of my answer to your answer, in case some one else encounters the same issue. You know, stating that WC can intercept errors and that they are to be found in `/wp-content/uploads/wc-logs/...`

Comment: That's right, it could be helpful. At first I didn't want to use the part of the solution, that was yours, not mine, but I hope added credit does clear the things up :-)